# NSXMLNode variable name not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmlelement

Strange error here.... For this piece of code:

```
NSXMLNode *root = [[ads_user_defined_manufacturer_model objectAtIndex:i] parent];
NSXMLNode *make = [root childAtIndex:0];
```

First line returns an error "Unused variable root", second line returns an error "'root' was not declared in this scope..

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It's highly likely that the problem is not in those two lines.   You may want to start looking for mismatched braces higher up in the function/method.   If you are going to need more help than this, please post the entire method, as well as the exact error messages, otherwise it's basically impossible to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it wasn't, you're right. It was way up in the code.. I had an if statement previous to the code above without any { } . Therefore only the first statement was being done in the if statement, with the other being done outside.

Hence the inability to see the variable decleration.

@gaige If you want to put your response as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer. Thanks.